# Почему говорят "архитектура x86"?

Tags: терминология, процессор

Почему говорят "архитектура x86" или "архитектура x64"? Почему не "архитектура 42"?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86896/discussion-on-question-by-user319055----x86).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что ранние модели процессоров Intel почти все(за редким исключением) имели название, которое состояло из цифр, последние 2 из которых были "86", отсюда и название "Архитектура x86"

Answer (score 1):

Название образовано от двух цифр, которыми заканчивались названия процессоров Intel ранних моделей — 8086, 80186, 80286 (i286), 80386 (i386), 80486 (i486).

Intel потому, что именно эта фирма разрабатывает железо (архитектуру, систему команд), а остальные в т.ч. Микрософт пишут под нее программы.

софт от майкрософт - как 86 от ...86.

x64 — это некорректная выдумка от майкрософта, грамотные люди пишут x86-64 или хотя бы amd64 (по названию изобретателя).

Answer (score 0):

Не бывает архитектуры х64, только архитектуры x86-64.
64-битное расширение, набор команд для архитектуры x86, разработанное компанией AMD, позволяющее выполнять программы в 64-разрядном режиме.